# How to use and combine AutoLayout's Multiplier and Constants?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I am new to auto layout.

I can't understand how the multiplier and constant works in auto layout.

Please tell me how does multiplier and constant works in auto layout.

Comment: Manually adjusting multiplier and constant isn't how you'd adapt between two screen sizes. Do you still want the explanation, or do you actually want to know how to adapt to different screens?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I do not want to use two different screens.I have 3.5 inch screen and by using auto layout need to adjust the 4 inch screen. Is it possible to adjust the 3.5 inch screen adjustment to 4 inch screen.  Just I want to know how to multiplier and constant works in auto layout.

Comment: What @jrturton is saying is that those are two different questions - How to make a view that adapts to different screens or how to use multiplier and constant.  It looks like you really want the answer to the first question, not the second.

Comment: @Paulw11, your right I want to know how to make a view that adapts to different screens.

Comment: Go through this [docu](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

xCode's AutoLayout works based on Constraints.
Constraints have Constant, Priority and Multipliers.

• • TL;DR • •

- Through Multipliers we can establish percentage relationships between
  items.
- Through Constants we can add absolute pixel values to items.

• • • • • • • • •

Constraints establishes relationships between two items, like so:

- **Item 01(i1): Door**
- *i1-Constraint*: Item 01 is 3 foot wide.
- *i1-Constraint*: Item 01 is 7 foot tall.
- **Item 02(i2): Window**
- *i2-Constraint*: Window is as wide as Door.

Because of the Constraint, Window now is 3 foot wide. This example is not using neither the Multiplier nor the Constant.

**According to xCode, the Multiplier is:**

> The Multiplier applied to the second attribute participating in the Constraint.

So you could possibly say:

- **Item 02(i2): Window**
- *i2-Constraint*: Window is as **twice** as wide as Door. (or 3 times, 4 times, 50%,...)

So, it applies a *multiplier* to the original Constraint.

**According to xCode, the Constant is:**

> The Constant added to the multiplied second attribute participating in the constraint.

So you could possibly say:

- **Item 02(i2): Window**
- *i2-Constraint*: Window is as wide as Door **plus** 1 foot.

So, it adds a *constant* to the original Constraint.